# Сравнить две QMap, содержащие proto объекты

Tags: массивы, qt, сравнение, qt4, google-protobuf

Нужно переопределить оператор сравнения для

`QMap<QString,proto-структура>`.

Можно ли обойтись без перебора каждого элемента QMap и сравнения каждого поля структуры? Упростить до сравнения хэш-сумм, например, или

```
toByteArray(),
```

что-то в этом роде. Как это лучше реализовать?

Comment: Вы можете преобразовать `QMap` во всё, что Вам заблагорассудится и потом сравнивать,  но по умолчанию сравнивать можно только поэлементно.

Answer (score 1):

QMap равен другому QMap когда все пары равны.
Так как у Protobuf нет оператора сравнения придется либо переводить сообщение в QByteArray с помощью функции SerializeToArray или в строку через DebugString, или в вашу структуру данных и только потом сравнивать. Добавлю что значения сравниваются через operator()== и ключи через оператор меньше . вот код

```
while (it1 != end()) {
    if (!(it1.value() == it2.value()) || qMapLessThanKey(it1.key(), it2.key()) || qMapLessThanKey(it2.key(), it1.key()))
        return false;
    ++it2;
    ++it1;
}
```

Так что просто сравнить мапы со структурами протобаф сообщений нельзя. Только если вы не определите для них operator==()